# `sudo !!` in eshell?

Tags: eshell, sudo

I was wondering how you could get the equivalent of `sudo !!` in eshell. I cant tell you the amount of times I have done this forgetting eshell doesn't have this feature built in.

I have looked through the available eshell functions and haven't seen anything that seems promising.

Comment: `M-p C-a sudo RET`?

Comment: yes I am able to make a macro that does the equivalent. Unfortunately it is deeply ingrained in me to just say `sudo !!` especially because I still use other shell programs that have this feature.

Comment: I poked around the code this morning in search of a solution and found eshell choking at `eshell-find-interpreter` when trying to pass the `sudo !!` command under the hood (programmatically).  I added a note to my wish list, but didn't see an immediately apparent solution already built-in.

Comment: Thanks for looking